# How to fix "At least two classes are needed to perform a LDA"?

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, face-recognition

I'm trying to run [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html#appendix) sample with OpenCV, but running it:

```
./facerec_video haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml csv_align -1
```

gives me this error:

> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (At least two classes are needed to perform a LDA. Reason: Only one class was given!) in lda, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/contrib/src/lda.cpp, line 1010
>       terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>         what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/contrib/src/lda.cpp:1010: error: (-5) At least two classes are needed to perform a LDA. Reason: Only one class was given! in function lda

How do I fix it?

Ps.: The xml is the standard **OpenCV**, and the csv is a sample with 2 images

Comment: Can you tell us what line it is failing on?

Comment: well, you need more than 2 *classes*, that is, images from at least 2 *persons*. easy to understand, that you want to start small, but usually, you'd need like 10-30 images per person for a decent result

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solved changing my csv.ext file to this style:

C:\Users\fsb\Desktop\image1_20_20_70_70.jpg;0
C:\Users\fsb\Desktop\face_20_20_70_70.jpg;1

Check if your file is according this and try again.